# Update Panel, confirm button and update progress don't seem to work together

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

At the moment I have no luck trying to get the three of them to work together  and i have had only luck with the updatepanel and update progress nothing the confirm button so far.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnEnter" runat="server" Text="Update" Width="180" Style="margin-left:157px;" 
                    OnClick="btnEnter_Click"  
                    CssClass="button-success pure-button"/>

                <asp:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender1" runat="server"
                    TargetControlID="btnEnter"
                    ConfirmText="Do you want to see submit?"
                    ConfirmOnFormSubmit="false">
                </asp:ConfirmButtonExtender> 
            </ContentTemplate> 
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"> 
            <ProgressTemplate> 
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="modal">
                <h2>Please Wait.....</h2>
                    <img alt="Loading..." src="/Images/loading.gif" />
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

I have used the javascript function confirm before this and have taken it out
it was just a onclientclick on the button.
      OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');"
  but I need to check validation of the page first before asking to submit but I am clueless about it.

here's the behind code atm for the button.

```
protected void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Page.IsValid )
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is the problem exactly?

Comment: basically when I implement the confirm button it breaks the update panel an nothing works within it, i have used previously the javascript confirm but i realised that i was submitting then checking for validity of my form

Comment: What are you using to trigger a postback on the update panel?

Comment: am using the button to postback

Comment: @MBiggs check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I will have a read of that now thanks

Comment: @MBiggs if that solved your issue, please mark as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this even easier and more efficient using client side like this:

you just need to add onclientclick attribute in your `<asp:Button ID="btnEnter"` control and remove the `<asp:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender1"` from your code.

it would be look like this then :

> ```
>    <asp:Button ID="btnEnter" runat="server" Text="Update" 
>                Width="180" Style="margin-left:157px;" 
>                OnClick="btnEnter_Click"  
>                CssClass="button-success pure-button"
>                OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to see submit?');"/>
> ```

and that's it!

So you **DO NOT** need `asp:ConfirmButtonExtender` anymore.

**UPDATE 1**

If you require to check the condition first on the code behind then you could use the code below:

> ```
>  protected void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>  {
>     if(Page.IsValid )
>     {
>           ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScrip(UpdatePanel1, this.GetType(), 
>       "confirm", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');", true);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I have already stated I have done that before, but I have the problem of validation, since the javascript runs before I check if the form is valid. Still I appreciate the answer

Answer (score 0):

try to Validate your form using jquery then throw the confirmation dialog if the valiation succeeded .

```
function ValidateForm(){
    //validation

    if(succeeded){
    return confirm('are you sure?');
   }else{
     return false
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#' + '<%= btnEnter.ClientID %>').click(function(){
    return ValidateForm();
   });
});
```